# Visual Studio 2015 properties window button not working for windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on a Windows Form application using designer view in VS2015. One problem that I have is that buttons in properties window never seem to work. For example in the attached picture, I cannot click on the arrow down [v] button on the right side in the DropDownStyle property to see the list and select the value (it does not seem to do anything).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdEL5.png]

I can get around this by hover my mouse cursor over the value and use my mousewheel to cycle through all the available options. However, this is a problem when I try to edit some property that has [...] button on the right side of it as I cannot scroll through the options.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJjr4.png]

Anyone know how to fix this? I tried reinstalling VS2015 and switching to VS2013 but the problem persists on both versions.

Some notes:

- I'm coding on laptop running windows 10.
- My laptop is not connected to any additional display.
- Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Comment: Weird! Can you try to workaround this using the keyboard, maybe? (Perhaps by pressing tab to move the focus to the button then space to activate it.) Also note also that anything you can set in the properties window you can do in code too.

Comment: I cannot edit designer code as it is auto-generated from the GUI designer. But the tab and space workaround works. Thank you for the quick solution!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Cameron, press tab to move the focus to [...] button then enter/space to access it.